# Users can post questions in MSE with 1 reputation, probably via the app

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, api

[According to Shog](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4875433#4875433):

> MSE rep-to-post is back at 2

Meaning that 2 reputation points are required to post here on MSE, due to the flood of off topic (mainly programming) questions by users who clicked the ToS change inbox message and didn't realize they are not on Stack Overflow.

However, six hours ago, [this question has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279126/feed-not-showing-and-cannot-scroll-through-questions-on-android-app), and OP clearly had 1 reputation when posting it, most likely via the android app.

This probably means the API does not impose the block, can this be fixed please?

Comment: Indeed. I still get the oops page when trying to go to the Ask page as a 1 rep user.

Comment: @Patrick "oops page" meaning error? I remember seeing a raw message (without any design) like "you need 2 reputation to post here"

Comment: No. A real oops page. The one with the panda if I am correct.

Comment: Reproduced this is an api bug. I was just able to post this question from the iOS app: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279134/245360

Comment: @Pat so the error page is also a bug, can you please post a separate bug report? (Have to go now.)

Comment: @m0sa isn't it API issue? And surely it's relevant only for MSE, it's the only site with this kind of block.... or isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another case for http://shouldiblamecaching. A new build of the API has invalidated the settings cache, the behavior should now be as expected.

Comment: Thanks, what about [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279136/ask-page-gives-error-for-1-rep-users)? (not sure it's related, probably not.)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced this bug when trying to post a question from the iOS app. That account wasn't able to post a question from the site.

I wonder about the impact though. I don't spamming would be very effective from the apps and regular users can't click the ToS update notification from the app, so preventing to post on MSE is not useful.

So is it a bug: yes. Is it important to fix: no. I guess eventually the block will be lifted some day.

Comment: Can you please try again now? According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279157/152859) it should be fixed.

Comment: Yes, fixed! @sha

Comment: Just wonder, what message you get?

Comment: The exact same wording as [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279159/245360) @sha