# Ask page gives error for 1 rep users

Tags: bug, reputation, asking-questions

The question page gives an *oops* error page when trying to ask a new question with 1 rep user:

> [image]

Comment: Hmm, yes, rep requirement is back at 2.

Comment: @rene it's back at 2 for few days by now, since May 4: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4875433#4875433.

Comment: The error page isn't clear and seems a bug. I would expect a clear message @rene

Comment: Patrick, can you visit any question? This might be [old bug coming back to life](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278688/users-with-1-rep-cant-view-any-questions-here-on-mse).

Comment: I think not @rene

Comment: Yes I can. @sha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is fixed now.

> [image]

Probably mosa fixed the issue together with [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279157/245360).